# How do you change fl_chart's touch tooltip into long press?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using fl_charts library and made a bar chart, normally you need to touch a bar to show it's tooltip, but i want to make it a long press instead, i have set handleBuiltinTouches to false, but I'm not sure how to display the tooltip after a long press.

I also tried setting up a custom painter overlay on top of the chart, which worked for the first time, before the custompaint widget covered the listener for the chart.

Full Code:

```
class BarChartControlState extends State<BarChartControl> {
  late double width;
  late PageLoader pageLoader;

  bool click = false;
  Offset? touchPos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      fl.BarChartData barChartData = createBarChartData(widget.controller.data);

      return Container(
        color: widget.controller.enable
            ? Colors.white
            : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                widget.showTitle
                    ? Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(widget.controller.chartTitle,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: FontSize.font1,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: width * 0.8,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: RotatedBox(
                            quarterTurns:
                                widget.chartType == "HorizontalBar" ? 1 : 0,
                            child: fl.BarChart(barChartData))),
                            touchPos == null
                    ? Container()
                    : Container(
                        height: width * 0.8,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: ToolTipPainter(
                              dx: touchPos!.dx, dy: touchPos!.dy),
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    
  }
  createBarTouchData() {
    return fl.BarTouchData(
        handleBuiltInTouches: false,
        longPressDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        touchCallback: (event, touchResponse) async {
          // touchResponse.spot.touchedBarGroupIndex;
          if (widget.controller.enable) {
            if (touchResponse != null) {
              if (touchResponse.spot != null) {
                switch (event.runtimeType) {
                  case fl.FlLongPressStart:
                    if (touchPos != touchResponse.spot!.offset ||
                        touchPos == null) {
                      touchPos = touchResponse.spot!.offset;
                    } else {
                      touchPos = null;
                    }
                    break;
                  case fl.FlTapDownEvent:
                    // focus
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                    pageLoader.focus(widget.controlName);
                    click = true;
                    print("click");
                    Timer(
                      Duration(seconds: 1),
                      () {
                        click = false;
                      },
                    );
                    break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          setState(() {});
        },
        touchTooltipData: fl.BarTouchTooltipData(
            fitInsideHorizontally: true,
            fitInsideVertically: true,
            rotateAngle: widget.chartType == "HorizontalBar" ? 270 : 0,
            tooltipBgColor: Color.fromARGB(200, 224, 224, 224),
            tooltipMargin: 10,
            tooltipPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            getTooltipItem: (fl.BarChartGroupData groupData, int groupIndex,
                fl.BarChartRodData rodData, int rodIndex) {

              return fl.BarTooltipItem(...);
            }));
  }
}
```